# Back and forth UTC dates in lua

Tags: date, lua, utc

I'm having problems converting a lua date to a timestamp and then obtaining back the original date from it. It does work for non UTC dates, but not with UTC.

Currently my example code is:

```
local dt1 = os.date( "*t" );
print( dt1.hour );

local dt2 = os.date( "*t", os.time( dt1 ) );
print( dt2.hour );

print( "-=-=-" );

local dt1 = os.date( "!*t" );
print( dt1.hour );

local dt2 = os.date( "!*t", os.time( dt1 ) );
print( dt2.hour );

local dt2 = os.date( "*t", os.time( dt1 ) );
print( dt2.hour );
```

Which yields the output:

```
12
12
-=-=-
10
9
11
```

So, in the second part, after obtaining the timestamp using `os.time( os.date( "!*t" ) )`; I don't know how to obtain the original date back. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See also the thread starting at http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2017-03/msg00461.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Working with "date tables" in Lua

Let `dt` be a "date table".
For example, a value returned by `os.date("*t")` is a "date table".

---

**How to normalize "date table"**
For example, after adding 1.5 hours to the current time
`local dt = os.date("*t"); dt.min = dt.min + 90`
you need to normalize the table fields.

```
function normalize_date_table(dt)
   return os.date("*t", os.time(dt))
end
```

This function returns new date table which is equivalent to its argument `dt` regardless of the meaning of content of `dt`: whether it contains local or GMT time.

---

**How to convert Unix time to "local date table"**

```
dt = os.date("*t", ux_time)
```

---

**How to convert Unix time to "GMT date table"**

```
dt = os.date("!*t", ux_time)
```

---

**How to convert "local date table" to Unix time**

```
ux_time = os.time(dt)
```

---

**How to convert "GMT date table" to Unix time**

```
-- for this conversion we need precalculated value "zone_diff"
local tmp_time = os.time()
local d1 = os.date("*t",  tmp_time)
local d2 = os.date("!*t", tmp_time)
d1.isdst = false
local zone_diff = os.difftime(os.time(d1), os.time(d2))
-- zone_diff value may be calculated only once (at the beginning of your program)

-- now we can perform the conversion (dt -> ux_time):
dt.sec = dt.sec + zone_diff
ux_time = os.time(dt)
```

Comment: The `os.time(os.date("!*t", 0))` yields `nil`, at least in UTC+2 timezone. changing the `0`s to `86400` (seconds in a day) solves the issue.

Comment: @JavierMr - Fixed in the answer.

Comment: In the 7th line, `dt` is not defined, probably meant `d2`.

Comment: `dt` is "GMT date table" (input of conversion), `ux_time` is Unix time (output of conversion).

Comment: ok, so continuation from the script at the beginning. perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the only solution to works this date , time and time zones is to use custom c-build method :

For example, to retrieve string in wanted format, I use this method:

```
static int idateformat(lua_State *L) {

    time_t t0 = (time_t) lua_tonumber(L,1); 
    const char* ptrn = lua_tostring(L,2);
    const char *tz_value = lua_tostring(L,3);

    int isinenv = 0;
    if(getenv("TZ") != NULL){
        isinenv = 1;
    }
    char old_tz[64];
    if (isinenv == 1) {
        strcpy(old_tz, getenv("TZ"));
    }
    setenv("TZ", tz_value, 1);
    tzset();
    char new_tz[64];
    strcpy(new_tz, getenv("TZ"));


    struct tm *lt = localtime(&t0);
    //"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    char buffer[256];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ptrn, lt);

    if (isinenv == 1) {
        setenv("TZ", old_tz, 1);
        tzset();
    }
    //printf("%ld = %s (TZ=%s)\n", (long)t0, buffer, new_tz);
    lua_pushstring(L, buffer);
    return 1;
}
```

Only this way I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong.

Lua uses the ISO C and POSIX date and time functions. In particular, `os.time` uses `mktime`, which only interprets the input structure according to the current timezone setting in the environment variable `TZ`. Unfortunately, these standards do not provide a function that interprets the input structure according to GMT/UTC.