# Lua : How to create a date table without time zone conversion

Tags: date, time, lua, timezone

In the [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-os.time), the function os.time() returns a number that represents the time. However, when pass in a table, it will contains a time zone conversion step, how do I skip this conversion?

For example,

```
os.time({year = 1970, month = 1, day = 2, hour = 0})
```

the output is 57600 in UTC+8 rather than 86400 in UTC+0

And

```
os.time({year = 1970, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 0})
```

the output is **nil** in UTC+8

Comment: "Date table" itself DOES NOT have a timezone.  "Date table" is similar to a usual wall clock - it does not know which timezone it is located in.  Only when you are converting "date table" to "Unix time" (the number of seconds since 1970), the timezone joins the game.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069253/6834680) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now manually adding the offset caused by the timezone diff after each function call.